# How can I improve my writing fluency in English?

Tags: english, written-language, second-lang-acquisition, writing

So this is a problem I've been struggling with for quite some time now. English is a second language for me despite the fact that I've spend a lot of my childhood years in Australia (grades 1 through 6), after which I moved to my home country where I rarely used English outside of school.
Now that I've moved back to Australia, I often get comments from my native speaking friends on both my written and spoken English. But no means would I say that I'm terrible at English. I'm able to speak and write the language with a great deal of proficiency and confidence, and with perfectly acceptable grammar. Nonetheless, my sentences seem to sound a little bit off at times, and often too formal (especially in speech).

I was able to identify some of the possible issues like using the wrong prepositions (eg. "make a note in my calendar"), or avoiding them altogether by relying on adjectives ("house keys" instead of "keys to the house"), which I suppose is fine but can make my sentences very clunky and difficult to comprehend. But there is also a more complex dimension to the problem, particularly relating to sentence structure and the way I tend to express my ideas. It is these aspects of my written language that I am most keen on improving.

Ill give an example. I was filling a form the other day that required an address. Since I was staying temporarily at my friends house, I wrote: "The address I provided is my for friend's house. I am staying with him for a few weeks. I will provide a new address when I move". My friend, who is a native speaker, told me to write: "I am staying at a friend's house for a few days until I find a place of my own". Now this will definitely seems trivial to native speakers, but its a sentence structure that wouldn't come naturally to me. Needless to say that it is by far a better sentence to use. Perhaps this doesn't have to do with my English per se, but more so with my writing skills in general, as I would probably have ended up with an equally terrible sentence had I used my native language!

But the issue for me is nonetheless the same, which leads to my question:
What do you think would be the best way for me to improve writing fluency so that I sound more like a skilled native writer? Will reading books help, and if so, can you recommend a few that I can start with? (I rarely read aside from academic papers, textbooks, and newspaper articles).
While I have come to terms with the fact that I most likely will never a reach a native level of proficiency, particularly in speech, nonetheless, any improvement would definitely help.

Any advice, comments, or criticism are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about personal fluency not linguistics. You should ask on the Writers, ELL or ELU sites instead. (Though it may not be on-topic there either.)

Comment: I disagree. The acquisition of fluency is very much a question to be dealt with by linguistics. It is part of language acquisition and speaks to fundamental questions of competence and performance. Although, this question is personal, it provides useful introspective data of which linguistics should make use.

Answer (score 1):

Reading widely can certain support your writing but it seems you already read quite a lot. However, from your example it seems that your reading predisposes you to more complex and formal sentence structure than is appropriate in all contexts. So including some fiction and informal correspondence in your reading may help. Listening to conversations would also be a good supplement - podcasts are a good source of semi-formal language. Also, remember the level of formality and approach to writing is as much cultural as linguistic. This post by Francois Grosjean illustrates that nicely: http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/life-bilingual/201408/bilingual-challenge.

Ultimately, the only thing that can improve your writing is practice in writing. There are many guides that will suggest structured programs such as this http://www.amazon.co.uk/Build-Fluency-Muscle-Six-Week-Programs-ebook/dp/B0055WYDQA.

But what it boils down to is: write regularly in small chunks in the genres you want to improve. Write even if you don't have anything to write, just for practice. You can even start by copying texts, then reformulating some of the sentences, then starting with mini essays and finally move on to longer texts.

Following a structured program will help because it will make it easier to measure your progress. But just allocating 15 minutes a day to writing (with gradually increasing complexity) should give you a boost.

Comment: +1. Helpful answer!